# css avoid slide in transition on hover

Tags: html, css

how to avoid slide transition in social icons on hover?

i want my all social icons in one png file and use transition also but it show up with sliding it not transition like two different images

```css
#social_icons {
  display:inline-block;
  background: url(http://www.gobothell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/FB-and-Twitter-icons-300x181.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 175px;
  transition: 0.5s ease, forward;
  border: 1.5px solid blue;
  margin:10px;
}
#social_icons:hover {
  background: url(http://www.gobothell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/FB-and-Twitter-icons-300x181.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-position: -150px 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 175px;
}
#social_icons2 {
  display:inline-block;
  background: url(http://www.florestrekkingtour.com/userfiles/images/FB_icons.png) no-repeat center center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s ease, forward;
  border: 1.5px solid blue;
  margin:10px;
}
#social_icons2:hover {
  background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/256x256/icontexto-inside-facebook.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
h2 {
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 10px lime;
  margin-top:45%;
}
```

```html
1 image
<div id="social_icons"><h2>Hover me</h2></div>
2 images
<div id="social_icons2"><h2>Hover me</h2></div>
```

Comment: So you actually don't want the transition.
If you'll remove the transition the image will suddenly appear.

Comment: @Dvir i want transition but with fade-in & fade-out like 2nd div example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS3 Transitions with a single element, the property your transitioning(changing) is background-position, hence the reason it appear sliding,

If a Fade In/Fade Out effect is what you require, you could use a CSS3 Animation to fade the element out on hover, move it to the desired background position then fade back in the new image.

If a Cross-fade is what you require there is either background-image: cross-fade()

```
background-image: cross-fade(url("logo-box.png"), url("logo-bare.png"),   50%);
```

But it has very limited browser support i.e. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-cross-fade.

Or probably the best option is using 2 elements and fade out one on top of the other, you could use a Pseudo Element (IE8+) to fake an extra element i.e.

```
#social_icons:before {
   content:"";
   display:inline-block;
   position:absolute;
   opacity:0;
   background:   url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inside/PNG/256x256/icontexto-inside-     facebook.png) no-repeat center center;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   background-size: 200px 200px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;  
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/kr7ec28q/ for working example

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/kr7ec28q/ for working example of Cross fading Pseudo element

Comment: i set transition to 1000s but it still render 0.5s [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kr7ec28q/4/)

Comment: Try again now, note: CSS3 transitions wont work in IE9 and below